# Merge cells having same values bottom down

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet where i need to merge the cells if the values are repeating

The expected is to merge the cell from A1 to A4 and have a single value A in it.

I have tried with,

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
//var values = range.getValues();
var numCols = values[0].length;

    values = [
        ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
        ["A", "B", "S", "D", "E"],
        ["A", "D", "C", "D", "E"],
        ["A", "B", "C", "D", "K"],
        ["c", "B", "W", "D", "K"],
        ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    ]

    for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        var placer = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
            if (values[i][j] == values[i + 1][j])
                range.getCell(i + 2, j + 1).setValue('');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show expected output for the ``values`` array. And what do you mean by merge?

Comment: _to merge the cell from A1 to A4 and have a single value A in it._ That part is obvious. What is not obvious is what happens to the the values in Columns B, C, D and E.

Comment: B1 and B2 will be merged to hold B and B4 to B6 will be merged to have value B in the second column, c3 and c4 will be merged to hold C and so on. The code will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to merge cells vertically when the cells have the same values to the vertical direction.
- You want to achieve the following situation.
- Input
  [image]
- Output
  [image]

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

The flow of my sample script is as follows.

1. Transpose the values.
2. Start and end addresses for merging cells are retrieved from the transposed values.
3. Merge cells using the retrieved addresses.

#### Sample script:

```
// Retrieve values from the active sheet.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// Transpose values.
var res1 = values[0].map(function(_, i) {return values.map(function(e) {return e[i]})});

// Merge cells.
res1.forEach(function(col, i) {
  var temp = {};
  col.forEach(function(row, j) {
    if (row === col[j + 1] && !(row in temp)) {
      temp[row] = j;
    } else if (row != col[j + 1] && row in temp) {
      sheet.getRange(temp[row] + 1, i + 1, (j - temp[row]) + 1, 1).merge();
      temp = {};
    }
  });
});
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

#### References:

- [merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

This is the answer for [the additional question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803864/merge-cells-having-same-values-bottom-down/56807478?noredirect=1#comment100242565_56807478).

#### Usage:

1. Manually select cells "A2:C6" on "Sheet1".
2. Run the script.

#### Script:

```
// Retrieve values from the active sheet.
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection().getActiveRange();
var sheet = range.getSheet();
var values = range.getValues();

// Transpose values.
var res1 = values[0].map(function(_, i) {return values.map(function(e) {return e[i]})});

// Offset
var r = range.getRow() - 1;
var c = range.getColumn() - 1;

// Merge cells.
res1.forEach(function(col, i) {
  var temp = {};
  col.forEach(function(row, j) {
    if (row === col[j + 1] && !(row in temp) && row != "") {
      temp[row] = j;
    } else if (row != col[j + 1] && row in temp) {
      sheet.getRange(r + temp[row] + 1, c + i + 1, (j - temp[row]) + 1, 1).merge();
      temp = {};
    }
  });
});
```

#### Result:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. This is perfect. But how do I modify the answer to work on the active selection only?

Comment: @Code Guy Thank you for replying. About your new question, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your issue. For example, if you select the cells "A1:E6" and you want to run the script for these cells, how about modifying from ``var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`` to ``var values = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection().getActiveRange().getValues()``. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize. If my understanding is not correct, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to confirm about it.

Comment: You can't vertically merge cells that intersect an existing filter.
Is the error I get when I run the script

Comment: @Code Guy Thank you for replying. At first, can I ask you whether I could correctly understand about [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803864/merge-cells-having-same-values-bottom-down/56807478?noredirect=1#comment100173154_56807478)?

Comment: @Code Guy About the filter, I couldn't see it from your question. So my answer doesn't consider about the filter. I deeply apologize that my answer cannot be used for various situations. About your current situation, unfortunately, I cannot understand. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information and sample Spreadsheet for replicating your new issue? I would like to correctly understand it. I apologize I cannot resolve your new issue soon. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Code Guy I have tried to replicate your situation from ``You can't vertically merge cells that intersect an existing filter. Is the error I get when I run the script``. But, unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this situation. I would like to confirm your situation. So I would like to propose to post it as new question by including the information for replicating your new issue. Could you please post it?

Comment: You can make a copy of the script and see the code, I have no merged cells, but still i get the error https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ROLQWyCHcyZQb7jHrJRPKDAYXDHujGvfgRAshle3m0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help